# Image doesn't scale on IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive, border-box

When I change the width of the browser window images doesn't scale on IE 11 or below. I does work with Google Chrome. I tried to add position: absolute, but it destroying whole layout.

Image css:

```
.auction-item-img-container {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px ) {
  .auction-item-img-container {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px ) {
  .auction-item-img-container {
    height: 270px;
  }
}
```

Parent and img both have `display: block; box-sizing: border-box;`

HTML:

```
<article onclick="AddCookieWithAuction(1185)" id="auction-1185">
<a class="auction-item-img-container" href="/Aukcje/PodgladAukcji/1185/1/1" style="background-image: url(/Content/images/backgrounds/empty.png)"> </a>
<!-- This part is responsive -->
<div class="auction-item-desc">
    <div class="auction-bar">
        <h4 class="auction-bar-author"><a href="/Aukcje/PodgladAukcji/1185/1/1">1</a></h4>
        <h5 class="auction-bar-title"><a href="/Aukcje/PodgladAukcji/1185/1/1">1</a></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="auction-price-container">
            <div class="actual-price-holder">
                    <span class="auction-price-label">Cena</span>

                <p class="auction-price"><a href="/Aukcje/PodgladAukcji/1185/1/1">123 PLN</a></p>
            </div>
                        <div class="auction-observe">
                <a onclick="acc.onObservedButtonClick(1185, this)" class="fa fa-star-o observe-icon"></a>
                <a onclick="acc.onObservedButtonClick(1185, this)" class="add-observe">Dodaj do obserwowanych</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="auction-type-container">
        <span class="auction-type"><a href="/Aukcje/PodgladAukcji/1185/1/1">Aukcja w trakcie</a></span>

    </div>
</div>
</article>
```

There is how it looks on both browsers.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJL58.png)

Comment: Add html code also.

Comment: could you place the code in fiddle as question is about image...

Comment: It looks same in both browser, What is your actual problem? And in which screen size?

Comment: But does it even matter which img it uses? I think it's more about some property working different at IE than Chrome and I'm missing it.

Comment: @VishalPanara with max width of 1024px and 480px. They just don't scale at all.

Comment: @VishalPanara but it's only media query, not max width of the class. I added an image, you can check it.

Comment: @P.Zietal Your given code is not enough, You need to place all working code here OR provide a fiddle.

Comment: @VishalPanara http://www.licyter.mefistosoft.pl/Aukcje you can check how it works here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see your layout [here](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) and all mobile devices, Your website is working properly in all devices. There is no meaning to watch your layout in internet explorer with resizing the screen.

Comment: But try to launch it on IE11/10, it clearly doesn't work. http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//licyter.mefistosoft.pl&w=800&h=600

Comment: I launched it in IE11 http://imgur.com/a/SRIvx and its working fine but if you resize the screen then there is a problem and i already told you that there is a no meaning to see your layout in IE with resizing the screen.

Comment: But I want it to be possible to resize the screen. That's the wole point of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late to the party, but I found this other SO answer that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174237/1914261

> IE11 seems to have some trouble with the initial value of the [flex-shrink property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). If you set it to zero (it is initially set to 1), it should work