# IE 11: Image doesn't scale down correctly within flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to use flexbox to place two images in a column. In this case, the `width` of the div container is smaller than the `width` of the image. In Chrome the image perfectly fits into the div container, but it doesn't in IE, and I don't know why.

```css
div.outer {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div.inner {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x360">
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x360">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Yifei/16cpckqk/

This is what I've got in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: I can't explain this, but you can always set a height of 100% on the image and manually define the height of the flexbox, if that helps :)

Comment: For some reason this is also fixed by setting `flex: 0 0 auto` on `div.inner` (or just `flex-shrink: 0`). Which is weird because in order to let the div shrink you are declaring it should not shrink.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

IE11 seems to have some trouble with the initial value of the [`flex-shrink` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). If you set it to zero (it is initially set to 1), it should work:

```css
div.outer {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
div.inner {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x360">
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x360">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You make it sound like setting `flex-shrink: 0;` is the correct way of ensuring a proper initial value. But the logically correct value here *is* `1` as I [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173213/ie-11-image-doesnt-scale-down-correctly-within-flexbox#comment71511073_42173213), even though the `0` happens to fix it.

Comment: I didn't say it's the correct way, my answer is a possible workaround to the problem. I didn't see your comment when answering... sry

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution destroyed my sticky footers in ie. So I solved this disturbing issue with the following non satisfying "only for ie JS"... . The px value instead the "height:auto" did the trick for me.

```
 if(fuBrowser =='ie'){
  var img = $("#teaser img");
    img.each(function() {
    $( this ).css({height: $( this ).height()});
    });
  }
```