# Fixing IE11's image rescale bug?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

As a little experiment, I am trying to fix the wrongly rescaled images one gets when opening the snopes.com homepage using IE11. (See screenshot)

[image: Snopes homepage]

Just to clarify, I am not the owner of the website.

I can see that the affected images belong to a class named "bg-image", but as a beginner, I have almost no idea where to go from there.

Can anyone suggest a quick'n'dirty fix that I can just try out from IE's devtools console?

Comment: That homepage is horrible. The best solution is simply to ditch the whole thing. The `sizes` attribute is the thing doing it there, though.

Comment: And CSS `object-fit`.

Comment: Just found this thread - can someone confirm if it is related?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173213/ie-11-image-doesnt-scale-down-correctly-within-flexbox

Comment: It might be related; you might be able to fix it via that method. Try it!

Comment: Use your browser's F12 tools to add the CSS rule. JavaScript'll come when you know what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- disable img.bg-image > -o-object-fit: cover and object-fit: cover
- disable img > max-width: 100% and height: auto
- change .bg-image To

  .bg-image {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

I checked and it worked on both chrome and IE.

Comment: Your answer was clear and straight to the point, and I was easily able to verify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is a polyfill for object-fit: cover with IE support:

https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images

just import that library into your site and your images gets transformed in IE to background-images automatically

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size: cover;` not `object-fit`, because it's not useful in ie11

Comment: On which CSS class specifically? I tried it in the F12 devtools, but with no visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

Nomally "object-fit" property not supported by the "IE" browsers,

```
-o-object-fit: cover;
object-fit: cover;
```

Reference link: https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

**Solution:**
Please refer the following solution link: [Object-fit: cover; alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717622/object-fit-cover-alternative/19718110)

**Note:**
Use the image as a background.

**Sample code from "snopes.com" :**

**Before :**

```
<img class="bg-image lazy-resource" src="https://www.snopes.com/tachyon/2015/05/titanic-P.jpeg?resize=865,452" alt="Did a Black Woman Named Malinda Borden Perish Because Titanic’s Lifeboats Were ‘Whites Only?’" data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: block;">
```

**Solution :**

**Method 1:** 
Apply background image to a element from the `image` tag.

```
<div class="set-bg-image">
    <img class="bg-image lazy-resource" src="https://www.snopes.com/tachyon/2015/05/titanic-P.jpeg?resize=865,452" alt="Did a Black Woman Named Malinda Borden Perish Because Titanic’s Lifeboats Were ‘Whites Only?’">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .bg-image {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .set-bg-image {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.bg-image').each(function(){
            var backgroundImageUrl = jQuery(this).attr("src");
            jQuery(this).closest('.set-bg-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImageUrl + ')');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Method 2:** 
You can assign the background image straightly to the 'set-bg-image' element while parsing.

Eg:

```
<div class="set-bg-image" style="background-image: url('https://www.snopes.com/tachyon/2015/05/titanic-P.jpeg')">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .set-bg-image {
        min-height: 150px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: On which class specifically? I tried it in the F12 devtools, but with no visible effect.